# Determining whether three points in s pace lie in the same plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I'm watching a multivariate calculus lecture, and the professor argues as follows. I'm not fully sure I understand it, but I'm going to try to paraphrase his argument.

Three points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ determine a plane provided that they aren't collinear. Call them $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P_3$, and suppose they aren't collinear. We can determine whether a point $P = (x,y,z)$ lies in the plane determined by those three points as follows. We create the vectors:
$$
\vec{P_1 P_3}, \vec{P_1 P}, \vec{P_1 P_2}.
$$
We then see whether the parallelepiped they span has non-zero volume. If this is a flat parallelepiped with no volume, $P$ lies in the plane.

Here is what I do not understand.

Why did we construct the vectors in this way? We included $P$ in one of the vectors, but only one. We joined all of the points to $P_1$. Could I have constructed the vectors in any way as long as I join two points? And why does showing that the three vectors lie in the same plane imply that the points lie in the same plane?

I'd appreciate any help with understanding this.

Comment: Draw a picture.  All will become clear.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I drew the picture. It makes sense to me that if the vectors lie in the same plane, the points lie in the same plane, but why were the vectors drawn that way (and why did I need to join them all to the point $P_1$?)

Comment: You draw the vectors linking the point because points along the vectors are linear combinations of those points, the foundation of what "spanning" means.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork My understanding is that a point in the plane must be a linear combination of $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P_3$. Given that, the vector definitions linking everything to $P_1$ doesn't make much sense to me still. Could I have linked everything to, say, $P_2$ or to $P$?

Comment: The thing is that a single point, like $P_1$ is a vector from the origin to that point in space and in particular to a plane that is somewhere in $\mathbb{R^3}$. If you want to do calculations regarding that plane, you ususally can only do that when that plane is through the origin. So that's why you take one point as a reference, say $P_1$, thern subtract it from all the others and then your plane is relocated in $\mathbb{R^3}$ through the origin.